# Mass-energy-equivalence's effect on SI units?

Tags: mass-energy, si-units, metrology

Maybe I'm misunderstanding mass energy equivalence, but can we use it to get rid of the [Joule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule) (or the kilogram) and have a single unit for both? It seems weird that if they're equivalent they'd have different units.

Comment: You can't get rid of one or the other, but you can (as is often done) choose units such that the speed of light is equal to one. Nevertheless, you still need factors of velocity to related one quantity to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to talk about the misunderstanding you have, but about the actual question you asked.The mass energy equivalence equation is $$E^2=(mc^2)^2 + (pc)^2$$ ($p$ is the momentum of the body).

If we use specialized units such that $c$ (the speed of light) becomes dimensionless, we *can* have the same units for mass and energy.

(This can be done, for example, by setting $c$ equal to $1$. This also equates time and length in terms of their dimensions, because if $c=1$, $300000000m=1 s$.)

Comment: So I do have a misunderstanding, right?

Comment: You should read this http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/equivME/#2